# Get current and previous value in flow's collect

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow, coroutinescope

I need to handle current and previous value in flow collect, so I need some operator that acts like that:

```
----A----------B-------C-----|--->

---(null+A)---(A+B)---(B+C)--|--->
```

One idea is something like:

```
fun <T: Any> Flow<T>.withPrevious(): Flow<Pair<T?, T>> = flow {
    var prev: T? = null
    this@withPrevious.collect {
        emit(prev to it)
        prev = it
    }
}
```

But this way there is no control over a context in which first flow will be executed. Is there more flexible solution?

Comment: what do you mean by "there is no control over a context in which first flow will be executed"? you can use `flowOn`

Comment: @IR42 for example: `someFunc().withPrev().map { / something / }.flowOn(customContext)`. So in this example flowOn will be applied only on `map` but not on `someFunc`

Comment: it's not true, did you test it? flowOn will also be applied to withPrevious and all "preceding operators that do not have its own context"

Comment: You are right, flowOn acts on first flow too. So seems this code works as expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

There's an operator which makes this very easy: `runningFold`

[The docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/running-fold.html) have an example on how to use it to collect each emission of a flow; this can be easily adapted to fit our needs

```
data class History<T>(val previous: T?, val current: T)

// emits null, History(null,1), History(1,2)...
fun <T> Flow<T>.runningHistory(): Flow<History<T>?> =
    runningFold(
        initial = null as (History<T>?),
        operation = { accumulator, new -> History(accumulator?.current, new) }
    )

// doesn't emit until first value History(null,1), History(1,2)...
fun <T> Flow<T>.runningHistoryAlternative(): Flow<History<T>> =
    runningHistory().filterNotNull()
```

You might need to tweak nullabilities to fit your usecase

Answer (score 4):

`Flow`s are sequential, so you can use a variable to store the previous value:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    var prevValue = null
    flow.collect { newValue ->
        // use prevValue and newValue here
        ...
        // update prevValue
        prevValue = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, wouldn't prevValue be always null in this case when the flow starts emitting? 

How could you make prevValue equals first value emitted from the flow?

Comment: It will be `null` during the first emission. Starting from the second emission and so on, if `newValue` is not `null`, `prevValue` will we updated.

Comment: Yep, any ideas on how could you make prevValue equals first value emitted from the flow?

Comment: Probably `flow.first()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make this very easily with `runningFold`, because with it, you can transform a flow into another using a fold operation. The is because `runningFold` does fold everything into one value like `fold`. Instead, it keeps all steps in between working as a history of all mutations. The only thing you need to be concerned with is that every returned value must be a pair, the first value must be null and the first pair must allow a null in the left value. Allowing a null as the accumulator means also that this value must be filtered out.

Roughly, you'll need to follow an example like this one:

```
val initial: Pair<String?, String>? = null
val allPairs = flow {
    emit("Oyster")
    emit("Clam")
    emit("Crab")
}.runningFold(initial) { lastPair, next ->
    lastPair?.run {
        val (_, last) = this
        last to next
    } ?: (null to next)

}.filterNotNull()
allPairs.collect {
    println(it)
}
```

This way you won't be needing to create a carrier class type, because your carrier class is already the `Pair` class.

You can test the difference with `fold` like this:

```
val initial: Pair<String?, String>? = null
val pair = flow {
    emit("Oyster")
    emit("Clam")
    emit("Crab")
}.fold(initial) { lastPair, next ->
    lastPair?.run {
        val (_, last) = this
        last to next
    } ?: (null to next)

}
println(pair)
```

Checkout more information about fold and different forms of it here:

1. [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html)
2. [runningFold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/running-fold.html)
3. [kotlin.collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections)